# Slow shared memory access via pointer

Tags: c++, c, opencv, embedded, embedded-linux

So, here is a setup:

My piece of software processes an image, captured from a device with a camera.

The device runs Linux on top of `RTOS` and has ARM cpu. A separate process manages image capturing. It uses shared memory and cyclic buffer. My piece of software gets `(unsigned char *)`, I wrap it using `openCV` `cv::Mat` using `.data` attribute. Image sizes are predefined and known.

Turns out processing this `cv::Mat` is very very slow. Simple `cv::resize` takes much more time than resize on image loaded from the disk. I mean much more, like x10 more time.

What is the best way to wrap data pointer with `cv::Mat`? What could be an issue of slow memory access?

I'm sorry for such a scarce description of my problem. Also we have some other piece of software that works fast with this pointer. (Can't look into source code).

Code example:

```
cv::Mat Frame(480, 640, CV_8UC1);

cv::Mat transformFrame(unsigned char *frame) {
    Frame.data = frame;

    cv::Mat res;
    cv::resize(Frame, res, cv::Size(240, 320), cv::INTER_LINEAR);
    return res;
}
```

`cv::resize` works very slow if src is cv::Mat wrapped around pointer to shared memory and relatively fast with loaded image from disk.

Comment: Did you compile your code with compiler optimizations enabled or not? If not; do so now.

Comment: Going to need a [mcve].

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, compiler optimizations are on and it's a Release

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings added

Comment: `The device runs Linux on top of RTOS` how Linux can be run on top of the RTOS?

Comment: @P__J__ by running a Linux kernel as the lowest priority task of the RTOS.  It is a rather old idea actually and was one of the first viable solutions to the problem of combining traditional full-OS capabilities with realtime needs.  However the question is desperately short on detail, and likely unanswerable as a result.